# Refreshing page on child route doesn't show the data for just that route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-router

I have a codesandbox set up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

// My Axios Getter is in /year
https://kom354q7r3.codesandbox.io/#/year/

```
  methods: {
    async getTDs() {
      const self = this;
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/500458/tds-data.json"
      );
      this.tds = response.data;
      this.y2001 = response.data.y2001;
      this.y2002 = response.data.y2002;
      this.y2003 = response.data.y2003;
      console.log(this.y2001, "this.y2001 From Year.vue");
      console.log(this.y2002, "this.y2002 From Year.vue");
      console.log(this.y2003, "this.y2003 From Year.vue");
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getTDs();
    console.log(this.tds, "From Year.vue - Before Mount");
  }
```

I get the data here and pass it to the child routes. In /year/2001:

```
  beforeMount() {
    this.tds = this.$parent.y2001;
    console.log(this.tds, "From y2001.vue's Parent ");
  }
```

I then pass this data to a child component on the child route.

```
<TDsByYear :tds="this.tds"></TDsByYear>
```

// Child Route that uses data from /Year Axios Call
https://kom354q7r3.codesandbox.io/#/year/2002

If I visit the above child route (/year/2002) I don't get any data in the yellow box for 2002, but navigating to 2001 and 2003 does show the data.

Then if I refresh on one of the other child routes(2001 or 2003), 2002 data will show up and the route I refreshed on shows no data.

If I go to the main /Years route and refresh, all of the data shows properly.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? I'd like people to link out directly to specific routes but redirecting may be a last resort.

Sandbox Editor: https://codesandbox.io/s/kom354q7r3

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title, and include a [mcve] in the question description, while off-site resources can be added as a reference, they shouldn't be needed to understand the question. Thank you.

Comment: Just stepped outside but will post code in a second. It seems to be an issue while refreshing or directly visiting the route so thought being there would be most important.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what the problem is? You first and third examples seem to work as intended, what is wrong with the way they implemented?

Comment: If you directly to a route: https://kom354q7r3.codesandbox.io/#/year/2002  no data is shown in the yellow box. It is the same if I refresh on any of the other routes. Shows the other routes data but not its own.

Comment: It appears to work in the editor view but when you select the full screen option it shows what's happening.

Comment: Have you tried this code outside of codesandbox?

Comment: Yes, with the same results unfortunately, in a dev environment in a vue-cli project.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you only make an ajax call when the the year view is called. If you go directly to 2002 view there is no ajax call thus no data to load the page. If you add the an ajax call to the 2002 view you can go directly to the page and see data. It looks like your are using a PWA format which I am not very familiar with but if I were doing this I would make your year.vue view the main component and them then make a child component that populates the data for the year that way you can pass down the chain using props and not have any problems. Also I would into [Arrow Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which would eliminate the need for `const self = this;` amongst other things, you could just use this. Also it is bad practice to load data for a bunch of components at once, its fine in your example but what would happen if you had 30 years of data your initial load would probably be terribly slow. Load what you need on each call and make multiple calls. If your data doesn't change much you can look into caching it instead of making multiple calls all the time